# Errors while installing wifi drivers on Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi, compiling

I purchased a new [Jinco Wifi Adapter](https://www.flipkart.com/jinco-n-600-usb-adapter/p/itmfezde9gf79ear) wifi adapter, but I am getting this error every time when issuing the `make` command:

```
[superusr@developer-pc ~]$ cd /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/
[superusr@developer-pc rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex]$ sudo make
[sudo] password for superusr: 

make -C /lib/modules/5.8.18-300.fc33.x86_64/build M=/opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.8.18-300.fc33.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist/halbtc8723b2ant.o
In file included from /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist/halbt_precomp.h:25,
                 from /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist/halbtc8723b2ant.c:14:
/opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist/../wifi.h:1493:2: error: unknown type name ‘__kernel_time_t’
 1493 |  __kernel_time_t last_suspend_sec;
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist/halbtc8723b2ant.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:497: /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/btcoexist] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1752: /opt/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.8.18-300.fc33.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:57: all] Error 2
```

`lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n
```

Kernel version -
kernel-5.8.18-300.fc33.x86_64

Fedora version - Fedora 33

Wifi - Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Comment: It is giving **Realtek Semiconductor Corp .** While doing lsusb

Comment: The wifi is on but it doesn't scan nicely and whenever a wifi detects, and we try to connect with it , it says network deactivated . It is giving make errors also . Is it a problem of kernel compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the provided `lsusb` info, `0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n`, what you're looking for is this driver:

https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

(Turning a comment into an answer to make it easily accessible).